# unable to create System DSN for oracle

Tags: oracle, odbc

I need to set up a DSN to connect to an Oracle db from R. I know that I have oracle clients install, because I can connect Oracle databases using PL/SQL. When I open Control Panel->Administrator Tools->Data Sources, I dont see Oracle in there. I only see Sybase, MSSQL and excel. How do I add Oracle under System DSN so that I can create a dsn to connect to an Oracle db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downloading the Oracle ODBC Driver
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-098155.html

I know when i used to install oracle for a program i would do custom install then under Oracle Windows Interfaces select Oracle ODBC Driver