# Unable to create DSN for Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle10g

This is weired problem that I am facing, I am unable to create a DSN for oracle.
I am currently using windows 64bit OS is windows7 ultimate, and oracle which I am using is oracle 10.2. But the issues is when I go to ODBC data source administrator I am not able to find Oracle in XE server. The strange behaviour..

When Open the same data source administrator from the path I am able to see Oracle XE server and set it. unfortunately I am not able to connect it to the database using this. I guessed that It had to do with permission settings, so I reinstalled oracle as administrator but that did not work. I read that we need to download an external odbc interface, even that did not work.

[unable to create System DSN for oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837387/unable-to-create-system-dsn-for-oracle)

How do I fix this? what is the issues here is it with the permission, envirnment variables etc?

Comment: Why aren't you able to connect with the workaround? Is your driver 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: If you use JDBC, then you should use the Oracle JDBC driver. You don't need a ODBC DSN.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel, I am trying to understand Type-1 driver.

Comment: @Alex poole. Yes its 64 bit driver..

Comment: @user2900314 Why, it is an outdated driver type that has even been removed from Java 8.